# What is the class for the intent with action = "MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-testing, android-camera-intent

I have an activity that starts another activity for result in this way:
`Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f = new File(CAMERA_PATH_TEMP);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);`

to test this activity, I want to use 
"Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(IntentFilter which, Instrumentation.ActivityResult result, boolean block)" 
or
 "Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(String cls, Instrumentation.ActivityResult result, boolean block)"
 but I don't know what should I pass as cameraIntent's class or how to use IntentFilter for this.

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I did some modifications.

Comment: Are you using the stock camera app to fulfill the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent? Do you want to test the system Camera activity?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Android developer docs for [Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html). It explains what each of the variables are used for.

For the IntentFilter constructor, the filter is *the set of intents this monitor is responsible for.*

For the String constructor, the String is *the activity class this monitor is responsible for.*